# Failed to install Qt 5 Visual Studio add-in

Tags: visual-studio, qt

My computer lost power by accident while installing *qt-vs-addin*.
After that I restarted my computer and found that the installation was incorrect. 
I tried to install it again. But a dialog showed:

> A previous installation of Qt 5 Visual Studio Add-in was detected. Please uninstall it before running this installer.

Unfortunately, I couldn't found *qt-vs-plugin in*: *Control Panel* -> *Uninstall a program*.

What should I do to remove the previous installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution found [here](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18768) suggests that it should be enough to delete the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Qt Visual Studio Add-in 1.1.11 – C:_Program Files (x86)_Qt4VSAddin]
```

- or some variation of it, depending on your plugin version, VS version and OS version.

Answer (score 0):

I can find add-in 1.2.4 from the Control Panel and unstall it.I don't know if due to I delete `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\xxx(seach for add-in for qt)` from Reg table before.

Comment: This may be a comment, but not a complete answer. And, yes, I know, you are not yet allowed to comment...